# Can I use adverbs in a different way?

Tags: adverbs

> **1**. *"Something scientifically in white helps to avoid car accidents."*
> **2**. *"Something  in white helps to avoid car accident scientifically  because clothes are bright."*

**1** means that ***being white is scientific***.
**2** means that ***the reason clothes are bright is scientific***.

The meaning I wish to convey is:

> Science has shown that hi-vis (high visibility) clothing can reduce
> car accidents.

Comment: Neither of those sentences makes sense. I assume you mean 'helps to _avoid_ car accidents'!

Comment: Science has shown that hi-vis (high visibility) clothing can reduce car accidents.

Comment: Yes I want to mean it with the sentences above.

Comment: No, you can't use _scientifically_ like that. As @WeatherVane suggests, you have to say something like 'Science has shown/proved that...'.

Comment: If you want the adverb in there, you could say, for example: "It is scientifically proven that white clothing helps to avoid car accidents."

Comment: I fix the second sentence.

Comment: Please don't make "live" edits to the question though: this isn't an "interactive" site.

Comment: okay...........

Comment: Note that **avoid** is often used when **prevent** is intended. They are not always interchangeable.  To **avoid** a traffic jam, take a different route; to **prevent** a traffic jam, keep traffic flowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use other adverbs in your examples, but not 'scientifically' the way that you have.

'*Scientifically*' means *by means of scientific methods and principles*. Your examples make no reference to scientific processes.

You could *possibly* say something like:

- Wearing white is *scientifically proven* to help to avoid car accidents.

...although I'm not convinced it would be a 'scientific' method that proved that. I think *statistically proven* would probably be more apt.

I know what you're trying to say - that the reflective quality of bright colours (specifically white) is a scientific principle - but I don't see the need for it here. I don't think anyone is in doubt that white is reflective. The purpose of your sentence seems to be about teaching safety, not science.

If you really want to discuss the scientific principle, you could say:

- Wearing white helps to avoid car accidents due to the scientific principle of reflection.

If you really need to use an adverb, it would have to act on the verb *to help*, so you could say:

- Wearing something white *dramatically* helps to reduce the chance of a car accident.

Answer (score 0):

Science is a subject such as physics, chemistry, and biology.

I would say "According to an official statistics of the Transportation Department, white clothing was effective to help to avoid car accidents."